# searchBar filtered tableViewCells didSelectItemAt indexPath display in navigationBar Title

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, filtering, uisearchbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYDts.png)[image]I am having trouble implementing a didSelectRowAtIndexPath from a searchBar filtered tableView cell. When I update the tableView list based on searchbar textDidChange, and perform a show segue to another ViewController, the navigationBar Title is always displaying the non-filtered tableViews indexPath 0. In other words, I would like to have the navigation title display the text from the didSelectAtIndex of search results tableView (not the original indexPath cell text from the non-filtered tableView). Hopefully that makes sense, and thanks in advance!

```
// viewDidLoad method
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
        searchBar.placeholder = " Search Places..."
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        fetchPlaces()

        placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

    }

    var placeList = [Place]()
    var placesDictionary = [String: Place]()

    // fetch places for tableView method
    func fetchPlaces() {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).child("Places")
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let place = Place()
                place.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                if let addedBy = place.addedBy {
                    self.placesDictionary[addedBy] = place
                    self.placeList.insert(place, at: 0)
                }
                //this will crash because of background thread, so lets call this on dispatch_async main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }  
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    // search variables
        lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
        var isSearching = false
        var filteredData = [Place]()

    // searchBar method
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
                isSearching = false
                view.endEditing(true)
                tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                isSearching = true
                filteredData = placeList.filter({$0.place?.range(of: searchBar.text!) != nil})
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    // tableView methods
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if isSearching {
                return filteredData.count
            }
            return placeList.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
            if isSearching {
                cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].place
            } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = placeList[indexPath.row].place
            }
            return cell
        }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let placeDetailsVC = CurrentUserPlaceDetailsVC()
    if isSearching == false {
    placeDetailsVC.navigationTitle = placeList[(indexPath.row)].place
    show(placeDetailsVC, sender: self)
    } else {
        placeDetailsVC.navigationTitle = filteredData[(indexPath.row)].place
        show(placeDetailsVC, sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string in your up coming ViewController.

```
class CurrentUserPlaceDetailsVC: UIViewController {
    var navigationTitle: String?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.title = navigationTitle
    }
}
```

Now instead of assigning the title directly to navigationBar you should assign it first to that string and then to navigationBar in viewDidLoad method of your viewController.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let placeDetailsVC = CurrentUserPlaceDetailsVC()
        // Get Cell Label
        placeDetailsVC.navigationTitle = placeList[indexPath.row].place
        show(placeDetailsVC, sender: self)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working...I wonder if I need to reset the indexPath when searchBar is displaying a filtered tableView? I added an image for reference.

Comment: Can you show me your data source method implementation??
numberOfRows & cellForRow also.

Comment: And one more thing does you tableView show the filter result as well ? If not then are you searching a method to filter the tableView or you are currently successfully displaying filter but want to pass data from select cell to next view controller?

Comment: Sure, I updated my code sample in my original posts to display related methods. My tableView is successfully showing filtered results on searchBar textDidChange, but it is not pushing the correct cell text to the next VC navigationBar Title when filtered result cells are tapped. So in my image attached, When I enter "B" and table filters display Bangkok, Thailand on tap of "Bangkok, Thailand" it pushes to the next VC but the navigationBar Title does not read "Bangkok, Thailand". It instead displays the original non-filtered indexPath.item of 0  (the first item in the non-filtered tableView).

Comment: Figured out my own question... not sure if it is the best way to do it but it works for now. See edited code for my didSelectRowAt indexPath method.